# FaceTime on my iPad

Tags: facetime

I have a number (3) in red on my FaceTime icon on my iPad but I can't see what it's for.  I've been onto my call history and no missed calls and I've now deleted all the calls made and received but the little red number is still there and I can't get rid of it. How do I do this and what was it for?

Comment: I had the same, for me it was the fact that the screen was showing Video, when the missed calls were actually on the Audio tab. Switching to the Audio tab meant that when I closed FaceTime, the numbers were gone.

Answer (score 2):

I have this happen frequently.  The missed calls appear to be calls coming in on my iPhone, and then the status is 'handed off' to my iPad.

Just viewing the 'Audio' or 'Video' tab doesn't clear the notification.

I find that I have to click 'edit' then 'done' on both the Video and Audio tab, then when I return to the home screen from the FaceTime app the notification goes away.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. Neither quitting the app nor powering off the iPad did anything.

Comment: Didn't help in my case... Have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Try closing out of the app or restarting your Ipad and the numbers should disappear. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Open facetime, on the left you have a small menu with an overview of who called you and who you have called.

When video is selected, open audio. Or open video when audio is selected. 
This is how I could solve this problem on my ipad.